# Dismiss of numeric Input not possible

Tags: react-native, input, react-native-elements

I am using an Input component with "decimal" keyboard. Unfortunately this keyboard has no button to dismiss itself.
My workaround is to show an icon on the right side with an appropriate action on it. However, this is of poor usability.

What is the best way to tackle this?

```
<Input
            ref={purchasePriceInput}
            placeholder="Enter purchase price"
            returnKeyType={'next'}
            keyboardType = 'decimal-pad'
            onChangeText={value => setPurchasePrice(value)}
            label={'Purchase Price'}
            labelStyle={styles.label}
            rightIcon={<Icon
                        name='check'
                        type='font-awesome-5'
                        color='gray'
                        onPress={()=>{purchasePriceInput.current.blur()}}   //<-- my workaround
                      />}
           >
           {purchasePrice.toLocaleString()}
          </Input>
```

Comment: Try to change `returnKeyType="done"`.

Comment: Great, with ´returnKeyType="done"´a "done-action appears. If you put your answer below I'll mark it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change `returnKeyType="done"`

**returnKeyType** determines how the return key should look.

The following values work across platforms:

- `done`
- `go`
- `next`
- `search`
- `send`

These values are just *appearance*.

So in your case, `next` works but it looks like a right arrow.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution if you want to detect press outside easily:

```
 //Container View
<View onTouchStart={()=>{
        Keyboard.dismiss()
    }}> 

    <TextInput
     onTouchStart={(e)=>{
                e.stopPropagation()
            }}
     />

</View>
```